# Meu web componente.html não é renderizado na aplicação, somente a tela app.component.html

Tags: html5, angularjs, angular, angular-routes, angularjs-components

estou iniciando meus estudos em Angular e estou enfrentando um problema que não entendo, uma vez que estou seguindo um tutorial e aparentemente fazendo tudo certo.

O problema é que criei um componente chamado Cliente, declarei suas variáveis, configurei o module... Mas quando tento acessar o **"/clientes"** que é o path que defini, ele continua mostrando somente a tela app.component.html, mesmo eu tendo referenciado corretamente o componente que quero acessar no path.

É minha primeira vez postando aqui, então não posso colocar imagem do site rodando, mas tudo o que aparece é a mensagem que coloquei dentro da app.component.html quando tento acessar o **http://localhost:4200/clientes**.

Segue o código:

**clientes.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Cliente } from '../cliente';
import { Guid } from 'guid-typescript';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'clientes',
  templateUrl: './clientes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clientes.component.css']
})
export class ClientesComponent implements OnInit {

  clientes!: Cliente[];
  formulario: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formulario = new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(),
      nome: new FormControl(),
      tipoCliente: new FormControl(),
      documento: new FormControl(),
      nomeFantasia: new FormControl(),
      CEP: new FormControl(),
      endereco: new FormControl(),       
      bairro: new FormControl(),    
      cidade: new FormControl(),     
      email: new FormControl(),    
      telefone: new FormControl(),
    });
  }

}
```

**clientes.component.html**

```
<p>clientes works!</p>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { ClientesComponent } from './clientes/clientes.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ClientesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FontAwesomeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'credenciamento-angular';
}
```

**app-routing-modules.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ClientesComponent } from './clientes/clientes.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'clientes',
    component: ClientesComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: vithor-lorencetti provavelmente está faltando o `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` na raiz do seu component ( `App.component.html` ), adicione a seu `App.component` a pergunta para te ajudarmos melhor

Comment: Willian, problema resolvido cara, muito obrigado!